# Hazelcast cache statistics, can't get number of puts of a given cache name

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, caching, hazelcast

I'm using Hazelcast as second cache of Hibernate in a Spring Boot application and I'm facing a problem to get some cache statistics. Calling

```java
this.hazelcastInstance.getMap(cacheName).getLocalMapStats()
```

I'm getting values that don't seem to me to be true. For example, for a given `cacheName`

```java
this.hazelcastInstance.getMap(cacheName).getLocalMapStats().getPutOperationCount() // = 0
```

and the same `cacheName` has a map of 14 elements when looking at

```java
hazelcastInstance.getDistributedObjects()
```

Do you have any idea why `LocalMapStats` object doesn't seem to have the right value?

Comment: Can you supply more information on why you think the counts are wrong ?

Comment: (The version of Hazelcast, Hibernate and the RegionFactory configuration would be useful also)

Comment: Yes, the counts seems wrong to me because it is equal to 0 whereas the map of that cache contains 14 elements

Comment: About versions, I have tested that initially using version 3.12.6 of hazelcast (springboot 2.2.6.RELEASE and hibernate 5.4.0.Final)
Then changed versions into 4.0.3 of hazelcast (and upgraded springboot to version 2.4.5)
=> As a result, I've got the same behavior comparing the cache map and the counts in the statistics object

Comment: FYI, I've made the comparaison in debug at the same break point (juste in case you thought I have done it in tow different times)

Comment: Are you able to test with Spring Boot 2.6.4 and Hazelcast 5.1, in case it's a known and fixed problem in older versions ? Also, are you using `HazelcastCacheRegionFactory` or `HazelcastLocalCacheRegionFactory` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243036/discussion-between-belham-and-neil-stevenson).

Comment: Chat seems to have expired. Did you get anywhere with checking the region factory type ?

Comment: Hello, yes I fount that the HazelcastCacheRegionFactory was set in the application.properties. Otherwise I've got the number of objects from the map directly (using hazelcastInstance.getMap(cacheName).size() ) instead of looking in the statistics

Comment: So does this mean you still have a problem ? If yes, are you able to create an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)